# Writing multiple items to a row in csv using for loop

Tags: python, csv

Suppose now I have a date and a list of groups(group A, group B, etc.) and would like to write all of them in one row in a CSV file. I have tried the following code but there are several problems.

```
import csv
with open('test.csv', 'w') as file:
output = csv.writer(file)
output.writerow('Date')  
for i in range(0,len(c)): 
 output.writerow([lst[i]]) #lst is the list containing the group number
```

The output here is

```
D a t e

Group A

Group B

Group C
```

The first issue is that each character in `Date` is treated separately, each of them appears in separate columns.

The second issue is that there is a new line between each row which is not desired.

Lastly, instead of writing them in rows, I want them to be in one row with multple columns. The ideal output should be as follows

```
Date Group A Group B Group C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine all the elements you want included in the row into a single list:

```
import csv
with open('test.csv', 'w') as file:
  output = csv.writer(file)
  out = ['Date']
  for i in range(0,len(c)): 
   out.append(lst[i])
  output.writerow(out)
```

Comment: `out = ["Date"] + c` (if `c` is a list) or `out = ["Date"] + list(c)` (if `c` is a tuple etc).